# Declaration of Array of Pointers Not Being Recognized

Tags: c++

```cpp
using namespace std;

namespace sdds {

    const int MAX_NO_OF_ITEMS = 10;

    class Menu {
        char* m_title;
        int indentation;
        int m_numofItems;
      //issue
        MenuItem*m_items = new MenuItem[MAX_NO_OF_ITEMS + 1]; // Declaration of MenuItem type not working


    public:

        Menu();
        Menu(const char* title, int indent = 0);
        Menu(const Menu& menu);
        ~Menu();
        bool isEmpty() const;
        void add(const char* str);
        int run();
        ostream& display(ostream& os);
        void display() const;
        Menu& operator=(const Menu& menu);
        operator bool();
        operator int();
        string& operator=(const char* str);
        Menu& operator<<(const char* item);

        //friend class MenuItem;

    };

    class MenuItem {

        char* i_name;
    //public:
        MenuItem();
        MenuItem(char*);
        MenuItem(const MenuItem& mi);
        void setMenuItem(char*);
        ~MenuItem();
        //ostream& display(ostream& os);
        ostream& operator<<(ostream& os) const;
        istream& operator>>(istream& os) const;
        MenuItem& operator=(const MenuItem& mi);
        friend class Menu;
    };

}
```

I am trying to make the `Menu` class hold an array of `MenuItem` pointers. `Menu` is a friend of `MenuItem`. I am having trouble trying to declare this array of pointers as I am receiving errors that tell me 'MenuItem' is not a type. "C4430 missing type specifier - int assumed." "C2143  syntax error: missing ';' before '*'"
and "C2238  unexpected token(s) preceding ';'"

Comment: Two problems.   Firstly, to declare a pointer to `MenuItem`, the class `MenuItem` must be declared (e.g. a forward declaration).   Second, the `new` expression being used as an initialiser -  `new MenuItem[MAX_NO_OF_ITEMS + 1];`,  - requires `MenuItem` to be DEFINED previously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class `MenuItem` should be defined first in your case then. It is not known at the time of Declaration

```cpp
using namespace std;

 namespace sdds {

     const int MAX_NO_OF_ITEMS = 10;
     class Menu;
     class MenuItem {

        char* i_name;
    //public:
        MenuItem();
        MenuItem(char*);
        MenuItem(const MenuItem& mi);
        void setMenuItem(char*);
        ~MenuItem();
        //ostream& display(ostream& os);
        ostream& operator<<(ostream& os) const;
        istream& operator>>(istream& os) const;
        MenuItem& operator=(const MenuItem& mi);
        friend class Menu;
    };

    class Menu {
        char* m_title;
        int indentation;
        int m_numofItems;

        MenuItem*m_items = new MenuItem[MAX_NO_OF_ITEMS + 1];

    public:

        Menu();
        Menu(const char* title, int indent = 0);
        Menu(const Menu& menu);
        ~Menu();
        bool isEmpty() const;
        void add(const char* str);
        int run();
        ostream& display(ostream& os);
        void display() const;
        Menu& operator=(const Menu& menu);
        operator bool();
        operator int();
        string& operator=(const char* str);
        Menu& operator<<(const char* item);

    };


}
```